# Zend smtp mailJet template

Tags: php, zend-framework, mailjet

I'm trying to send email on my zend app Via mailjet.
It works but cannot load the desired template.
Code:

```
 $config = array('ssl' => 'ssl',
                'port' => 465,
                'auth' => 'login',
                'username' => 'mailjet api username',
                'password' => '8mailjet api key');


            $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('in-v3.mailjet.com', $config);
            $mail = new Zend_Mail();
            $mail->addHeader('X-MJ-TemplateLanguage',true);
            $mail->addHeader('X-MJ-TemplateID','validationV2'); 
          // This is the template I wanna use.(above)
            $mail->setFrom('test@test.org', 'You');
            $mail->addTo('test@test.org', 'Anybody');
            $mail->setSubject('My first email by Mailjet');
            $mail->setBodyHtml('wxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

            $mail->send($transport);
```

If I could get any help woudl be great!

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the numerical ID of the template in `X-MJ-TemplateID`. If it still doesn't work, file a [support ticket](https://www.mailjet.com/support/ticket/)

Comment: Tried but same result, I've opened a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. It could be that Mailjet v3 for SMTP Relay is not Zend compatible.
However, the workaround I have tested is to use directly the Mailjet API after importing 'mailjet/mailjet-apiv3-php' via composer, like so :

```
    $mail = [
        'FromEmail' =>  'test@test.org',
        'FromName' => 'You',
        'To' => 'Anybody <test@test.org>,
        'MJ-TemplateID' => 1,
        'MJ-TemplateLanguage' => true
    ];

    $mj = new Client('mailjet api username', '8mailjet api key');
    $mj->post(Resources::$Email, ['body' => $mail]);
```

I'm curious what Mailjet's answer was for your support ticket, however!